# Turning table data into "atomic vector" in R

Tags: r

I'm really new to R.  I have the following:

```
library(stringr)
data <-read.table("C:/dataAnalysis/dataset_317_1.txt")
d<-data[5]
set<-str_count(c("corn", "cornmeal", "corn on the cob", "meal"), "setosa")
ver<-str_count(d, "I.versicolor")
vir<-str_count(d, "I.virginica.")
arr<-c(set,ver,vir)
arr
```

R says:

```
> ver<-str_count(data, "I.versicolor")
Error: String must be an atomic vector
```

My file is table of tab delimited data, with string in the fifth column.  How can I make the data from my table that I read into an atomic vector and make R happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data you want to analyze is in the fifth column, your code for defining "d" is incorrect.

```
d <- data[[5]]
```

or

```
d <- data[,5]
```

will work correctly.

data[5] keeps the data frame structure, while data[[5]] or data[,5] outputs only the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to the above answer, avoid using codes like data[5] unless you want to preserve the original class of the data set, whether it is an array, a list, a matrix or a data frame. If you want to understand more about subsetting, there's an excellent ebook called "R Fundamentals & Graphics" which will be a good desk reference for you.